# How to reorder the below list data

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I will have a list which contains date in this manner `mm/YYYY` . I need to reorder the data in the list.

**First :**

In list I will have data as a below

```
        yearList.add("042011");
        yearList.add("052011");
        yearList.add("062011");
        yearList.add("072011");
        yearList.add("082011");
        yearList.add("092011");
        yearList.add("102010");
        yearList.add("112010");
        yearList.add("122010");
        yearList.add("012011");
        yearList.add("022011");
        yearList.add("032011");
```

I used `Collections.sort(yearList);` but the out put gave me as

```
[012011, 022011, 032011, 042011, 052011, 062011, 072011, 082011, 092011, 102010, 112010, 122010]
```

But I need output as Below.

> [102010, 112010, 122010, 012011, 022011, 032011, 042011, 052011,
>   062011, 072011, 082011, 092011]

Comment: You sorted your array elements by their **natural order**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you current list is been sorted in "text natural" order, which won't sort numbers (or dates) as you might expect.  Instead, you need to provide a custom `Comparator` to change the way in which the sorting works, for example

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SortList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> yearList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        yearList.add("042011");
        yearList.add("052011");
        yearList.add("062011");
        yearList.add("072011");
        yearList.add("082011");
        yearList.add("092011");
        yearList.add("102010");
        yearList.add("112010");
        yearList.add("122010");
        yearList.add("012011");
        yearList.add("022011");
        yearList.add("032011");

        Collections.sort(yearList, new Comparator<String>() {
            private DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy");

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                int result = 0;
                try {
                    Date d1 = format.parse(o1);
                    try {
                        Date d2 = format.parse(o2);
                        result = d1.compareTo(d2);
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        result = -1;
                    }
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    result = 1;
                }
                return result;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(yearList);
    }

}
```

Which outputs `[102010, 112010, 122010, 012011, 022011, 032011, 042011, 052011, 062011, 072011, 082011, 092011]`

Take a closer look at [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its woked to me. Sure i will check above Collections type.

Comment: @developer This is essentially an example based on the answer of vandale, so if you find it useful, an up-vote is appreciated, but the credit should go to vandale as he responded first...IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You can  use  the [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) form instead and pass it a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will take into account the format of the strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use comparator and use the first 2 character of the string and parse them as int

**sample:**

```
Collections.sort(yearList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(2, 6)) == Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(2, 6)))
               return Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(0, 2)) - Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(0,2));
            else
                return Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(2, 6)) - Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(2, 6));
        }
    });

    System.out.println(yearList.toString());
```

**result:**

```
   [102010, 112010, 122010, 012011, 022011, 032011, 042011, 052011, 062011, 072011, 082011, 092011]
```

Comment: This is probably just a personal thing, but beware of converting a "date" value to `int` for comparison, it might not always work the way you expect...

Comment: @MadProgrammer well as long as the last 4 character are year and first 2 character are months then it would work.

Comment: *"well as long as"* - Famous last words ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ahahaha :))

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the `mmyyyyy` is getting sorted as a simple `String`

if you use this method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)  you can provide your own method for comparison.

In this method your will need to split the `mm` and the `yyyy` and put them into `int` variables in order to sort as to you requirements.